# Submenu appear effect

Tags: html, css

I have the following lines of code in my website...

**HTML:**

```
<div id="left-sidebar" class="span3 sidebar">
    <ul class="product-categories">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-60"><a href="product-category/hot-deals/">Hot Deals</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-61"><a href="product-category/starter-kits/">Starter Kits</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-62"><a href="product-category/mechanical-mods/">Mechanical Mods</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-65"><a href="product-category/batteries-chargers/">Batteries &amp; Chargers</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="cat-item cat-item-78"><a href="product-category/batteries-chargers/battery-cases/">Battery Cases</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-67"><a href="product-category/accessories/">Accessories</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-68"><a href="product-category/diy-supplies/">DIY Supplies</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-70"><a href="product-category/coming-soon/">Coming Soon</a></li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-71"><a href="product-category/clearance/">Clearance</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar ul.product-categories li ul.children {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.sidebar ul.product-categories li:hover ul.children {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Which ultimately makes - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrKvy/.

How would I make it so that when the user hovers over a listed item, the child menu 'gradually appears', fading from invisible to visible over a duration of 200ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default opacity to 0 and change it to 1 when hover.

```
.sidebar ul.product-categories li ul.children {
    opacity: 0;
}
.sidebar ul.product-categories li ul.children {
    display: inline-table;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
}

.sidebar ul.product-categories li:hover ul.children{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some assistance with your answer, as it doesn't seem to work - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJmhi/

Comment: Updated. I wrote 'oapcity' instead of 'opacity'.

Comment: I'm still not getting the effect of the child-items gradually appearing - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pbrcy/.  Is there something wrong with how I've implemented your answer?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Alejandro.  How would you go about removing the empty space that the child-item is taking up?

Comment: Changing the ul display's value from block to table. http://jsfiddle.net/codeams/7RJfF/2/

Comment: I'm sorry the correct display value is inline-table. http://jsfiddle.net/codeams/7RJfF/3/